# rgbdslam dataset

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros fuerte on ubuntu  12.04
what is the easiest way to use dataset provided here:
http://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset
I am doing as described here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/9785/rgb-6d-slam-performance-on-a-robot/
but I cant see anything

Is it possible to create local map, not only global?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123246/rgbdslam-dataset/) by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found somewhere on this forum a launch file, that after modifying some topics started to work. I pass below the content of launch file if sb. will need it in future. Due to lack of carma I cannot mark it as correct answer

```
<!-- This file demonstrates the use of SIFT features for online SLAM with a Kinect.
     The openni driver has to be started seperately -->

<launch>
  <node pkg="rgbdslam" type="rgbdslam" name="rgbdslam" cwd="node" required="false" output="log" > 
    <!-- see rgbslam_sample_config.launch for all available parameters and their default values -->
      <param name="config/topic_image_mono"              value="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>

<param name="config/topic_image_depth"             value="/camera/depth/image"/>
<param name="config/topic_points"                  value=""/> <!--if empty, poincloud will be reconstructed from image and depth -->
<param name="config/camera_info_topic"             value="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
<param name="config/bagfile_name"                  value="/home/wilk/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_datasets_rosbag/rgbd_dataset_freiburg2_xyz.bag"/>
<param name="config/start_paused"                  value="true"/>

      <param name="config/wide_topic"                    value=""/>;
      <param name="config/wide_cloud_topic"              value=""/>;
      <param name="config/drop_async_frames"             value="true"/> <!-- Check association of depth and visual image, reject if not in sync -->
      <param name="config/feature_detector_type"         value="SURF"/><!-- If SIFTGPU is enabled in CMakeLists.txt, use SURF here -->
      <param name="config/feature_extractor_type"        value="SURF"/><!-- If SIFTGPU is enabled in CMakeLists.txt, use SURF here -->
      <param name="config/matcher_type"                  value="FLANN"/> <!-- FLANN (not avail for ORB features), SIFTGPU (only for SIFTGPU detector)  or BRUTEFORCE-->
      <param name="config/max_keypoints"                 value="2000"/><!-- Extract no more than this many keypoints (not honored by SIFTGPU)-->
      <param name="config/min_keypoints"                 value="1600"/><!-- Extract no less than this many ... -->
      <param name="config/optimizer_skip_step"           value="5"/><!-- optimize every n-th frame -->
      <param name="config/store_pointclouds"             value="true"/> <!-- if, e.g., only trajectory is required, setting this to false saves lots of memory -->
      <param name="config/individual_cloud_out_topic"    value="/rgbdslam/batch_clouds"/>;
      <param name="/config/use_gui" value="true"/>
    <!-- see rgbslam_sample_config.launch for all available parameters and their default values -->

  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) with karma: 67 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-02-14**:
Note that the file contains a hard coded path to the bagfile, which needs to be adapted.